# Python- 'Automate the boring stuff'- while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.8

A fairly simple question from an absolute beginner. Please bear with me.

--I'm following along in the book 'Automate the Boring Stuff' and am at while loops. ---

--The following Python 3.8 code--:

```
name = ''
while name != 'your name':
  print('Please type your name.')
  name = input()
print('Thank you')
```

--The intention is get the 'Thank you' to print when the while loop exits.  I suppose this means the 'thank you' line must be indented with the 'while' loop line. But when I do this I get :

File "stdin", line 4
print('Thank you')

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

P.S. I can get the 'Thank you' line to print but inside the while loop. when I indent it with the preceding lines of code.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're using Python 3.8?  What output do you get from `python --version`?

Comment: Python 3.8.2  ------------

Comment: How are you running the code?  Are you using an interactive python shell from the command line?  Or an IDE, or something else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Im running it in IDLE. But I just found that if I run as a script I don't have the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing that in REPL, try adding an empty line after `name = input()` (won't be necessary if this code is run as a script, ie. from a file)